# An inequality for two positive series

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence, reference-request

Let $\{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ and $\{ b_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be two non-increasing sequences of positive numbers,

$$
\sum _{n=1} ^\infty a_n  < \infty,  \ \ \  \   \ \   \  \  \  \  \  \ 
\sum _{n=1} ^\infty b_n  = \infty.
$$

Let $\{ u_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be an increasing sequence of positive numbers, $u _n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  Is it true that the inequality
$$
\sum _{n=1} ^m a_n u _n  \leq \sum _{n=1} ^m b_n u _n  \   \   \  \   \  \  \  \  \ \ \ 
 \   \   \  \   \  \  \  \  \ \ \ 
(1)
$$
holds for all sufficiently large $m \in \mathbb{N}$? If not, is it true that (1) holds for infinitely many $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I assume that $u_n<\infty$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$?

Comment: @R.Burton yes, each $u_n$ is finite but $ \lim_{n \to \infty} u_n  =  \infty$.

Comment: Searching on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%20_%7Bn%3D1%7D%20%5Em%20a_n%20u%20_n%20%20%5Cleq%20%5Csum%20_%7Bn%3D1%7D%20%5Em%20b_n%20u%20_n%24&p=1), I found what seems to be a similar, but harder, version of your question (Q2 on [China TST 1986](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h37431p234101)). [Here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h37412p234015) is a proof.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I wasn't aware of this tool, thanks. I do not think the positive answer follows from Q2 of China TST 86. What follows is that (1) is a consequence of $m$ inequalities $a_m \leq b_m$, $a_m + a_{m+1} \leq  b_m + b_{m+1}$, ..., $\sum _{n=1} ^m a_n \leq \sum _{n=1} ^m b_n $. To get a positive answer, it would still be necessary to  show that those $m$ inequalities hold for sufficiently large $m$, or at least for infinitely many $m$.

Answer (score 1):

The question that asks if the proposition must hold for all sufficiently large $m$ must be answered in the negative. I have at the moment no answer for the second question.

Set for  $n\ge 1$

$$a_n=\frac1{2^n},$$

and define $i_n \in \mathbb N$ recursively as

$$i_1=1, i_{n+1}=i_n+\frac2{a_{i_n}}, n \ge 1$$ and then

$$b_n=\frac{a_{i_k}}2, \text{ if } i_k \le n < i_{k+1}.$$

The $i_n$ sequence is easily seen to tend to $\infty$, so the definition of $b_n$ makes sense.

What happens is that $b_1$ starts out as half of $a_1=\frac12$, but then $b_n$ stays constant for as long as necessary to reach sum 1, which is 4 for summands for $b_1=\frac14$. Then $b_5$ is again half of $a_5=\frac1{32}$ and $b_6, b_7,\ldots$ are all the same, until again the sum of all $b_n$'s, starting from $b_5$ becomes one (64 summands, so $i_2=5+64=69$).

That means both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ fullfill the conditions of the problem, but still $b_{i_k} = \frac{a_{i_k}}2 < a_{i_k}$ for each $k$.

The condition (1) is equivalent to

$$\sum_{n=1}^m (b_n-a_n)u_n \ge 0$$,

and that means whatever $\sum_{n=1}^{i_k-1} (b_n-a_n)u_n$ for any $k$ may be, you can choose $u_{i_k}$ big enough such that $\sum_{n=1}^{i_k} (b_n-a_n)u_n < 0$, because the last summand has a negative coefficient $(b_{i_k}-a_{i_k})$.